# IllegalStateException Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR in Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, styles, android-support-library

Im using Android support library 25.0.0 and everything works well, however if you have my app installed and I upgrade to latest version 25.3.1 some devices crash, seems only in Samsung, HTC, and One plus. the stack trace is:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:207)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
```

and this happens when I use

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Im extending from Theme.AppCompat ,However I extend for this main theme and I override this data

```
<style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

The problem is, before the update I have no crash report of this topic, after I updated I got this crash on my Crashlytics.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> try this as your main theme of your Application and Use your toolbar where you need actionbar by using `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/primary_light</item>

    </style>
```

And remove this custom theme

```
<style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```